# Does an interactive bash process implicitly send any signal other than SIGHUP to its job?

Tags: bash, signals, job-control

Does an interactive bash process implicitly send any signal other than SIGHUP to its job? By implicitly, I mean not as a consequence of a user's request to send a signal to a job.

It helps to answer [Does `disown` apply only to SIGHUP or some or all the signals?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492355/does-disown-apply-only-to-sighup-or-some-or-all-the-signals)

Comment: the source code of bash does. e.g. interactive bash's SIGHUP handler does, huponexited and interactive bash's pre-termination cleanup does.

Comment: to bash user, what bash does is implicit. to bash, what the kernel does is implicit. I meant the former.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a number of instances which can be found by searching calls to `kill` and `killpg` in [`jobs.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c) in the Bash source code.

One example is the handling of stopped jobs when `exec` is run, or when the shell exits: [the shell sends `SIGTERM` and `SIGCONT`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?id=36f89ff1d8b761c815d8993e9833e6357a57fc6b#n1454) to all stopped jobs.

Comment: Thanks. (1) are such cases rare? (2) I don't know how to search for kill in the online hosted repository, even though you might have mentioned it before a little.

Comment: (1) As rare, or otherwise, as sending `SIGHUP`. (2) Ctrl+F in your browser works wonders when searching in a single file ;-).

Comment: Does disown make interactive bash not send signals other than SIGHUP to a job?

Comment: That question is nonsensical. What does `disown` do? How does Bash know which processes are jobs it is supposed to manage?

Comment: Does this make sense? Does disown apply to SIGHUP only or also to some other signal(s)?

Comment: I’ll ask again: what does `disown` do?

Comment: disown removes a job from the job list of an interactive shell. One consequence is that it prevents the shell from sending SIGHUP to a disowned job. But I am not sure if it also applies to other signals.

Comment: Hence my followup question above: how does Bash know which processes are jobs it is supposed to manage? (... and therefore send signals to?)

Comment: bash maintains a list of jobs. disown can remove a job from the list. May I ask if disown applies to SIGHUP only or also to some other signal(s)?

Comment: If `disown` removes a job from the list of jobs, how can Bash send it a signal?

Comment: Can you give an example, some commands in bash, where disown applies to a signal which is not SIGHUP?

Comment: `disown` doesn’t “apply to signals”; it removes processes from the list of jobs. This is all commentary on your other question though so I won’t update my answer here.

Comment: What I meant is does `disown` affect any other signal than SIGHUP?

Comment: "One example is the handling of stopped jobs when exec is run, or when the shell exits: the shell sends SIGTERM and SIGCONT to all stopped jobs."  Does the shell send SIGTERM and SIGCONT to disowned stopped jobs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059114/how-can-i-search-for-a-string-in-the-gitweb-interface-of-a-git-repository and https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47889579#47889579

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [what Stephen said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492471/80216#492477),
it looks like bash sends SIGCONT to stopped processes
when you issue a `fg` or `bg` command, or otherwise resume a stopped job. 
And it sends a SIGSTOP *to itself* when you issue [a `suspend` command](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/suspend.def).